# Lines starting with colons in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, syntax

Playing around with DB projects, Visual Studio generated a change script with the following lines:

```
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS, ANSI_PADDING --etc.;
SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF;

GO
:setvar DatabaseName "Foo"
:setvar DefaultFilePrefix "Foo"
:setvar DefaultDataPath ""
:setvar DefaultLogPath ""

GO
:on error exit
GO

:setvar __IsSqlCmdEnabled "True"
GO
IF N'$(__IsSqlCmdEnabled)' NOT LIKE N'True'
    BEGIN
        PRINT N'SQLCMD mode must be enabled to successfully execute this script.';
        SET NOEXEC ON;
    END

GO
USE [$(DatabaseName)];

GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [SomeIndex]
    ON [dbo].[SomeTable]([SomeColumn] ASC);

GO
```

What is the significance of the colons at the beginning of the lines? [This Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2177978/what-does-the-colon-sign-do-in-a-sql-query) says that the colon is for bind variables, but then what does the colon in `:on error exit` do?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## It's SQLCMD

What you have is a [`sqlcmd`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx) script.
The `sqlcmd` utility lets you enter Transact-SQL statements, system procedures, and script files at the command prompt.

And sqlcmd has some [sqlcmd specfic commands that start with a colon](http://archive.is/P2H7R#selection-4287.0-4307.44).

Some general info on sqlcmd below.

[image: Screenshot of CLI with sqlcmd running]

You can write SQL statements that are executed after you type `GO`. In the example, first the database `AdventureWorks2012` is selected and after that a `SELECT` is executed.

### -i to include scripts

However, you also have the possibility of executing a prepared script using the option **-i**, for example:

[image: Script01.txt]

[image]

### -v to pass in a value

You can also create scripting varibales with the notation **$(name)** and passing a value from the command prompt using the option **-v**

[image: SCript02.txt]

[image]

Apart from the command prompt, code including scripting variables can be executed from SQL Server Management Studio, by selecting `SQLCMD mode` in a query window.

[image: Icon for SQLCMD mode inside SSMS GUI]

### :SETVAR

In this environment the way you can set the values of the scripting variables is using **:SETVAR** command

[image]

### :ON ERROR

The **:ON ERROR [ EXIT | IGNORE]** sets the action to be performed when an error occurs during script or batch execution.

#### Ignore

[image: Screenshot for on error ignore]

When the `IGNORE`option is used, the error is ignored and the batch or script continues executing. However, the error message is printed.

#### Exit

[image: Screenshot for on error exit]

When the `EXIT` option is used, the execution is stopped and exists.

Answer (score 4):

`:On Error` is an Execution Control Command in sqlcmd.

The post you referenced is referring to Oracle but the script you posted is for Sql Server's [sqlcmd utility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx) or [sqlcmd mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174187.aspx)

> `:On Error [ exit | ignore]`
>
> - Sets the action to be performed when an error occurs during script or batch execution.
> - When the **exit** option is used, **sqlcmd** exits with the appropriate error value.
> - When the **ignore** option is used, **sqlcmd** ignores the error and continues executing the batch or script. By default, an error message will be printed.

Comment: According to the first link, `All sqlcmd commands, except GO, must be prefixed by a colon (:)`, so that explains why the lines start with colons.